# $x^2 + y^2 = \frac{y - xy'}{x + yy'}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve: $x^2+y^2= \dfrac{y - xy'}{x+yy'}$

Now, the differential equation is not homogeneous, it does not match the form required for integrating factor and I'm unable to make it separable. So I don't know how to start. Can you please help?

Comment: Are you sure that the equation is correct ? Probably, this would lead to an implicit equation $F[x,y(x)]=k$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%C2%B2%2By%C2%B2%3D+%28y-xy%27%29%2F%28x%2Byy%27%29) @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: What else did I think and comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2= \dfrac{y - xy'}{x+yy'}$$
$$x+yy'= -\dfrac{xy'-y}{x^2+y^2}$$
Note that:
$$ \left (\arctan \dfrac{y}{x}\right)'=\dfrac{xy'-y}{x^2+y^2}$$
And that:
$$x+yy'=\dfrac  12 (x^2+y^2)'$$

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint}$: In differential notation, the expression simplifies

$$(x^2+y^2)(x+yy') = y-xy' \implies (x^2+y^2)(xdx+ydy) = ydx - xdy$$

So it would make sense to use polar coordinates

$$\begin{cases}x = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}dx = \cos\theta \:dr - r\sin\theta \:d\theta \\ dy = \sin\theta \: dr + r\cos\theta\:d\theta\end{cases}$$

$$xdx+ydy = r\cos^2\:dr-r\sin\theta\cos\theta\:dr + r\sin^2\theta\:dr + r\sin\theta\cos\theta\:d\theta = r \:dr$$

$$ydx - xdy = r\sin\theta\cos\theta\:dr - r^2\sin^2\theta\:d\theta-r\sin\theta\cos\theta\:dr-r^2\cos^2\:d\theta = r^2\:d\theta$$

which means the first line in polar differential notation instead of Cartesian would be

$$(r^2)(r\:dr) = r^2\:d\theta \implies r\:dr - d\theta=0$$

Are you able to solve it from here and convert back to Cartesian for your answer?

Comment: Typo: $ydx−xdy = - r^2dθ$

Comment: $$r dr + dθ = 0 \\ \int r dr + \int dθ = 0 \\ \frac {r^2}2 + θ = C \\ x^2 + y^2 + 2 \tan^{-1}\frac yx = c$$